# substr not working in array

Tags: php

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 21.2694 USD  ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 21.2694 USD ) )

(this is basicall google currency converter)

echo $arr[0][0]; //output is 21.2694 usd

But i want Output like 21.26 USD

What is tried is ,
echo substr($arr[0][0],0,5);//For this substr line i expected output is 21.26

But am getting just blank page,

Where i made mistake

i want 21.26USD as the output if i give the input as 21.2694 USD

Basically am doing the currency converter (google api)

But api producing result as 29.5645 USD from in this , i want to make out put as 29.56 USD ,

This is my snippet ,

```
   
    $from_currency = "GBP";
    $selected_currency = 'USD';
    $txt_cash_price = '10';
    $txt_card_price = '14';

    $get_currency = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$txt_cash_price&from=$from_currency&to=$selected_currency");
    preg_match_all("/(.*)/", $get_currency, $matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $caprice = $matches[0][0];

       OUPUT SOMTHING LIKE THIS 15.2070 USD
```

But i want output as 15.20 USD

Comment: Enable error reporting using `error_reporting` and `display_errors`.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be 21.27 USD?

Comment: Do you want the result to be truncated or rounded ?

Comment: They do have an API you know. http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/2.0/developers_guide_js.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
$str = '15.2070 USD';
echo round($str,2)." USD"; //15.21 USD
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `number_format()` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)):

```
string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals ] )
```

So here is an example:

```
echo number_format((float)$arr[0][0], 2), " USD";
```

What happens here is that we get the right value from the array, and cast it to `float`. That  makes PHP remove the text part of the value, so you are left with only the number. Then `number_format` formats it to include 2 decimals, and finally we echo out `" USD"` afterwards.

Comment: you should not let number_format deal with removing the text as its designed to take strings in the parameters and does not have a set type, it will cause more memory than needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `substr()` for this. Use [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/number_format).

```
echo number_format($arr[0][0], 2);
```

however, the way you do it should work in principle, too (even though it's not the best way). Make a test output of `$arr[0][0]` to see whether it contains any value.

Comment: @Bharani ah, you need to remove the "USD".  Try  `rtrim($caprice, "a..z ");` or use `(float)` as @Vegard recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to make the value of the array a float instance so do this

`$price = (float) $arr[0][0];` //This will covert it to pure float number.

Then you can use number_format to get the decimal places just right.

Heres my test case:

```
$myArray = array(
   array(
      '21.34957 USD.'
   )
);

$float = (float)$myArray[0][0]; //21.34957 | removes the text and turns to a float.

echo number_format($float, 2); //21.35
```

Comment: i cant aboe to made any chanes in that array value,
If i cant able to remove the USD means i simply use the substr,
But i dont know why, i cant able to make any changes in the array value,

Comment: Cna you please make your comment readable. "If i cant able to remove", "i cant aboe to made any chanes", " cant able to make" ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the plain number, with none of the extra formatting that `number_format()` adds, you can use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
 echo sprintf('%0.2f', 21.2694);    -> 21.26
```